# How to solve differential equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, equations

How can I show that `y(t)=Yo/Yo+(1-Yo)e^-at` is the solution of the differential equation `dy/dt=ay(1-y)` using MATLAB. What function should I use?

Comment: see https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html

Comment: You could also use differentiation and simplification of the difference of both sides of the equation to verify the solution. Embrace the power of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to simulate the results use the ode's family

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

else you can define your equation in syms and use diff

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html

other wise you can solve it numerically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.